# Need Correct Open Graph Meta Tags When PHP Data Passed Through URL

Tags: php, post, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I'm creating a site utilizing PHP that draws data from a mySQL database.  The content that is drawn is constantly changing and linked to a unique ID.  Although a lot of content is pulled on a main page, each facebook-send button links to the contents unique ID on a separate page.  I'm passing the information through the URL in the facebook send (ie. link:  www.example.com/info.php?id=5 )

My problem is that the send button is not recognizing the Open Graph Meta tags for the page - it displays the wrong picture and wrong title.  I've tested with the debugger - and it works for the receiving page (www.example.com/info.php), but not with the added data.  That said, once I plug in the full URL with data (www.example.com/info.php?id=5) into the debugger - that page gets crawled & all send buttons linking to that exact URL now populate with the correct picture and title.

Because the content on my site is constantly changing I can't manually have facebook crawl each page of potential URLs with each data ID.  **Is there a way I can pass data through the URL and have facebook-send button recognize the Open Graph Meta Tags on the receiving page to display for every potential ID? Note: it's just one picture and title I want for all links.**

I thank you in advance for your time, I'm slightly new to programming and your help is sincerely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We do a lazy crawl, so the first person to Send might not get the image right away, but if you wait 30 seconds and try again it should show up.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!  Unfortunately I still am encountering the same problem two days later.  I understand that it takes a bit for facebook to crawl the site - and I read putting in the URL into the debug forces the crawl to occur then.  

I think my issue is more that the specific URL's with data are not crawled - for example www.example.php?id=1, then www.example.php?id=2.  So still only the sites I've had explicitly crawled by putting their full URLs into the debugger display the correct title & picture.